# Probability of a particles spin in the $x$-direction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, quantum-mechanics

This question may turn out to be trivial, but it's worth asking. I'm working through Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, problem 4.32 part a.

> a) If you measured the component of spin angular momentum along the $x$-direction, at time $t$, what is the probability that you would get $+\hbar/2$?

My linear algebra is pretty weak, which may correspond to my problems in understanding the material. All the sources I've found online about probability in a specific direction say "the probability is just $|\langle \psi_x|\psi\rangle|^2$", and don't elaborate on why this is the case.

I understand that the probability is simply the absolute value of the wave function squared, but I'm not sure why, when seeking the probability in a certain direction, you take the inner product of the component in question and the wave function. i.e., $\langle\psi_x|\psi\rangle$.

Could someone point me in the direction of a proof regarding this, or give me a general idea of why this works?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on the physics site. I see that you are registered and have 4 questions there already, and this question hasn't been asked there yet.

Comment: I would have. But for some reason, they have banned me from asking questions. I'm not sure why, they state it's because I have a bad track record with asking questions. I'm not sure what's wrong with the questions I asked.